# LINQ distinct by 2 properties and by create date

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, distinct

I have a list that contains `Person` model like this:

```
public class Person
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }      
        public int Rating1 { get; set; }
        public int Rating2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

`Rating1` never equals `Rating2`.

**Question:**

How get a list that `Rating1` or `Rating2` equals given rating value, and last created elements from that list?

I explain my opinion by sample. Assume that here is list:

```
Rating1    Rating2    CreateDate
4          8          2013-08-15 05:12:00
9          4          2013-08-15 07:12:00
8          4          2013-08-15 08:12:00
5          20         2013-08-15 09:12:00
20         4          2013-08-15 10:12:00
20         5          2013-08-15 11:12:00
4          9          2013-08-15 12:12:00
```

Assume that I send rating value '4' as paramater to this method

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetList1(int r) {}
```

and get a list:

```
8          4          2013-08-15 08:12:00 //because there are many [4 and 8] couples, but this created last.
4          9          2013-08-15 12:12:00 //because there are many [4 and 9] couples, but this created last.
20         4          2013-08-15 10:12:00 //because there is one [4 and 20] couple, this also  created last.
```

If I send rating value '20' as parameter to  `GetList1()` method, I want to get a list:

```
 20         5          2013-08-15 11:12:00 //because there are many [20 and 5] couples, but this created last.
 20         4          2013-08-15 10:12:00 //because there is one [20 and 4] couple, this also  created last.
```

Comment: to use GroupBy and Distinct together

Comment: and 2 properties confuse me

Comment: Thanks to all for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
int r = 4; // your rating

var res = from p in lst
          where p.Rating1 == r || p.Rating2 == r
          group p by new { Min = Math.Min(p.Rating1, p.Rating2), Max = Math.Max(p.Rating1, p.Rating2) };

var res2 = res.Select(p => p.OrderByDescending(q => q.CreateDate).First());
```

I use the `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` to make the lowest rating the first one, and the biggest one the second. So `4, 8` is equivalent to `8, 4`

Or, (more or less equivalent):

```
var res = from p in lst
    where p.Rating1 == r || p.Rating2 == r
    group p by new { Min = Math.Min(p.Rating1, p.Rating2), Max = Math.Max(p.Rating1, p.Rating2) } into q
    select q.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreateDate).First();
```

or pure LINQ (but less readable)

```
var res = from p in lst
    where p.Rating1 == r || p.Rating2 == r
    group p by new { Min = Math.Min(p.Rating1, p.Rating2), Max = Math.Max(p.Rating1, p.Rating2) } into q
    select (from s in q orderby s.CreateDate descending select s).First();
```

Comment: Removed my answer as you have the correct grouping. Good use of Min and Max there. +1

Comment: +1 for great solution, you need to get the last element based on `CreateDate` in group to complete the answer

Comment: @Cuong The OrderByDescending and Take(1) are there for this.

Comment: @xanatos: Great solution, but grep for `4` and replace with `r`.

Comment: There is no more LINQ in the last solution than the previous.  LINQ is in reference to the `OrderByDecending` method itself.  Whether you use method syntax or query syntax, it's still LINQ either way.

Comment: You could also use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` rather than `.Take(1)`.

Comment: @Tory You are at one or two versions ago :-) I can use First() because thanks to the GroupBy I know every group has at least an element (otherwise it couldn't exist)

Comment: which approach is more faster?

Comment: @xanatos Huh.  Weird.  I refreshed and it showed all of the new comments, but not your edit.

Comment: The three LINQ expressions should be equivalent. The first one is subdivided in two sublinqs, while the second one is a merge of them partially in functional syntax and the third one is pure linq of the second one.

Comment: @xanatos, if you need, which of them, whould you use, please? first approach?

Comment: @JhoonBey The second. It's the most compact and shows what you are trying to do in a succint way.

Comment: my list has much data, that is why i need the fastest of them.

Comment: Thanks for advanced answers and great solution

Comment: When I use second approach in my code, i get such error:  

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Min(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @JhoonBey You see what happens when you don't tell **exactly** what you want? You should have told it was for EF. Replace `Math.Min(p.Rating1, p.Rating2)` with `(p.Rating1 <= p.Rating2 ? p.Rating1 : p.Rating2)` and `Math.Max(p.Rating1, p.Rating2)` with `(p.Rating1 >= p.Rating2 ? p.Rating1 : p.Rating2)`

Comment: You are right, of course, my question was not advanced. Just i get so error: 
"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead"

Please, sorry for boring.

Comment: @JhoonBey No problems. Try with the `FirstOrDefault` then. It won't change the result.

Comment: @xanatos, thank you very much. You saved my 1 week or more may be.

Answer (score 1):

You can group on an array of the two ratings that's sorted to get the items with that unique pair of ratings.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetList1(IEnumerable<Person> source, int rating) {
    return source.Where(person => person.Rating1 == rating
        || person.Rating2 == rating)
        .GroupBy(person => new int[] { person.Rating1, person.Rating2 }
            .OrderBy(r => r), new SequenceComparer<int>())
        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreateDate)
            .First());
}
```

You'll need this comparer to be able to compare the arrays by their values, rather than their references, in `GroupBy`:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.Take(5).Aggregate(37,
                (acc, item) => acc * 79 + item.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the primary advantage of this answer over one that uses `Min`/`Max` to "sort" the values, is that this can effectively scale to N different related fields.  If you add a `Rating3` all you need to do is add that OR to the `Where` and the `GroupBy` and you're done.

Comment: What's up with your `GetHashCode`? The hash is equal to `37+79*(sum of first five hashcodes)`? This seems like a buggy implementation of an enterprise anti-pattern.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce Right, mixed the operations up.  I usually never do that.  Thanks for point it out.

Comment: Even with the edit it's still at tremendous risk of an overflow. This simply isn't the way to hash a collection.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce Yeah, was already editing that in.  Granted, I always work in projects compiled to `unchecked`, but it's still good to have it there.  Note that having it overflow isn't bad, or in any way problematic.  I fully *expect* it to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var things=new[] {
  new {Rating1=4,Rating2=8,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 05:12:00")},
  new {Rating1=9,Rating2=4,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 07:12:00")},
  new {Rating1=8,Rating2=4,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 08:12:00")},
  new {Rating1=5,Rating2=20,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 09:12:00")},
  new {Rating1=20,Rating2=4,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 10:12:00")},
  new {Rating1=20,Rating2=5,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 11:12:00")},
  new {Rating1=4,Rating2=9,CreateDate=DateTime.Parse("2013-08-15 12:12:00")}
  };

int r=4;
var result=things
    .Where(t=>t.Rating1==r || t.Rating2==r)
    .GroupBy(t=>new {r1=Math.Min(t.Rating1,t.Rating2),r2=Math.Max(t.Rating1,t.Rating2)},
    (key,group)=>group.OrderByDescending(c=>c.CreateDate).First());

result.Dump();
```